# Viewcontroller not Loading bottom views

Tags: ios

The Probelm is  I'm putting subviews of Viewcontroller in storyboard and when i run it on simulator it doesn't load whole subviews (Bottom Subviews)
As SHown Below....This Is at storyBoard
[image]

And Now this at simulator
[image]

Comment: In your story board for the controller select top bar as navigation bar, and then design UI. Also you should set auto layout constraints to properly display UI objects on screen.

Comment: ThnXx for Reply,were I'll get Top bar in stroyboard

Answer (score 0):

Set Topbar of your controller to Navigation bar and design UI. See attached screenshot.

[image: Setting Top bar]

Comment: thnxxx Bharath,Now I understand...Thnxx Alott

Comment: But in some viewcontrollers navigation bar is coming automaticallly and in some viewcontrollers it is not why!!(in storyboard)

Comment: When you segue any of the controller (lets say 'cntrlA') to other controller (lets say 'cntrlB'), if 'cntrlA' has Navigation then its automatically added to 'cntrlB' also. Otherwise you see plain controller without navigation.

Comment: Actualy I had made a custom baseviewcontroller which is i'm using in every viewcontroller and I had define a custom navigationcontroller method in it so I don't need a top bar in storyboard but when I dont use top bar in storyboard I have to put all subviews Up from the bottom because bottom views are not visible

Comment: What is the 'done' 'title' with gray color background view in your screenshot attached in question ? Is that a bottom view ?

Answer (score 0):

firstly, u shouldn't put your e-mail address in the screenshot... then it looks like you added a `UINavigationBarItem`... some views don't render unless they're added to the right controller subclass, like `UINavigationBarItem`.  Just try a different `UIView`

Comment: YEs I have added navigationBar Item

Comment: `UINavigationBarItem` doesn't render unless it is added to a `UINavigationController`